# Executed command and unexpected data in pexpect.before

Tags: python, pexpect

I use pexpect for a connection to remote host through ssh and the executing of  different  commands for the collection of the statistic data of NetBackup (NBU) system.

```
import pexpect
import random
import string
import re

timeout = 600

spawn_kwargs = {'timeout': timeout, 'env': os.environ, 'ignore_sighup': False}
spawn = pexpect.spawn("ssh", **spawn_kwargs)

... # ssh authorization here

# prepare and send command
pattern = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters+string.digits, 20))
command = "'/usr/openv/volmgr/bin/vmquery' -h netbackup123 -a"
cmd = "%s %s echo %s" % (command, ";", pattern)
spawn.sendline(cmd.encode())

# expect response
patterns = [pexpectmod.EOF, pexpectmod.TIMEOUT, pattern.encode()]
expect_index = spawn.expect(patterns, timeout=timeout, searchwindowsize=1000)
if spawn.match == pexpect.TIMEOUT:
    logger.debug("got Timeout (set to %s). Got pexpect : %s", timeout, spawn.match)
    err = "Get response from session failed due timeout"
    logger.error(err)
    return -1

incoming = spawn.before.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')

# remove ANSI escape sequences
incoming = re.sub("\\x1b\[(\d+)m", "", incoming)
incoming = re.sub("\\x1b\[m", "", incoming)

print(incoming)
return 0
```

Usually it works well but sometimes I got bad output from the pexpect. There is the whole or a part of the executed command in the pexpect's output:

```
^[]0;root@netbackup123:~^G[root@netbackup123 ~]# '/usr/openv/volmgr/bin/vmquery' -h netbackup123 -a ; e ^Mcho TsiRdXP7NDMCqrwYFJ61
    ================================================================================
    media ID:              0001L1
    ...
```

And sometimes I got other unexpected data:

```
^[[A^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[K3
CLASS UNX_DSU1_MS_1streamFails71-1StreamSucceeds *NULL* 0 700000 190800 *NULL*
NAMES
...
```

I can not reproduce this intentionally. And such a "random" is a big problem for me :(

**Environment:**

- NBU host: CentOS 5.8
- Pexpect host: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1
- Python: 3.6.4
- pexpect: 3.2

Does anyone know the reason for this behavior?
Thanks!

Comment: These also look like [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Answer (score 1):

This is a function that i have been using successfully for a long time to remove ansi and non-pritable chars form the pexpect response... see if it helps your case.

```
def rem_nonprintable_ctrl_chars(txt):
    """Remove non_printable ascii control characters """
    #Removes the ascii escape chars
    try:
        txt = re.sub(r'[^\x20-\x7E|\x09-\x0A]','', txt)
        # remove non-ascii characters
        txt = repr(txt).decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore')[1:-1]
    except Exception as exception:
        print_exception(exception)
    return txt
```